# Custom huggingface Tokenizer with custom model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am working on molecule data with representation called SMILES. an example molecule string looks like `Cc1ccccc1N1C(=O)NC(=O)C(=Cc2cc(Br)c(N3CCOCC3)o2)C1=O`.

Now, I want a custom `Tokenizer` which can be used with Huggingface transformer APIs. I also donot want to use the existing tokenizer models like `BPE` etc. I want the SMILES string parsed through regex to give individual characters as tokens as follows:

```
import re

SMI_REGEX_PATTERN = r"""(\[[^\]]+]|Br?|Cl?|N|O|S|P|F|I|b|c|n|o|s|p|\(|\)|\.|=|
#|-|\+|\\|\/|:|~|@|\?|>>?|\*|\$|\%[0-9]{2}|[0-9])"""

regex = re.compile(SMI_REGEX_PATTERN)

molecule = 'Cc1ccccc1N1C(=O)NC(=O)C(=Cc2cc(Br)c(N3CCOCC3)o2)C1=O'
tokens = regex.findall(molecule)
```

It is fairly simple to do the above, but I need a tokenizer which works with, let's say `BERT` API of Huggingface. Also, I donot want to use lowercase conversion, but still use BERT.

Comment: All the what the tokenizer does is splitting a string into tokens and assign numbers to these tokens. All you need to do now is creating a mapping of potential tokens to unique numbers to have a tokenizer.

Comment: Please post the solution if you have solved it

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet provides a tokenizer that can be used with Hugging Face transformers. It uses a simple Word Level (= mapping) "algorithm".

```py
from tokenizers import Regex, Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import WordLevel
from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import Split
from tokenizers.processors import TemplateProcessing
from tokenizers.trainers import WordLevelTrainer
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast

SMI_REGEX_PATTERN = r"""(\[[^\]]+]|Br?|Cl?|N|O|S|P|F|I|b|c|n|o|s|p|\(|\)|\.|=|-|\+|\\|\/|:|~|@|\?|>>?|\*|\$|\%[0-9]{2}|[0-9])"""
BOS_TOKEN = "^"
EOS_TOKEN = "&"
PAD_TOKEN = " "
UNK_TOKEN = "?"
MODEL_MAX_LENGTH = 512

smi = "CC(C)(C)c1ccc2occ(CC(=O)Nc3ccccc3F)c2c1"

smiles_tokenizer = Tokenizer(WordLevel(unk_token=UNK_TOKEN))
smiles_tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Split(
    pattern=Regex(SMI_REGEX_PATTERN), behavior="isolated", invert=False
)
smiles_trainer = WordLevelTrainer(
    special_tokens=[BOS_TOKEN, EOS_TOKEN, PAD_TOKEN, UNK_TOKEN]
)
smiles_tokenizer.train_from_iterator([smi], trainer=smiles_trainer)
smiles_tokenizer.post_processor = TemplateProcessing(
    single=BOS_TOKEN + " $A " + EOS_TOKEN,
    special_tokens=[
        (BOS_TOKEN, smiles_tokenizer.token_to_id(BOS_TOKEN)),
        (EOS_TOKEN, smiles_tokenizer.token_to_id(EOS_TOKEN)),
    ],
)

tokenizer_pretrained = PreTrainedTokenizerFast(
    tokenizer_object=smiles_tokenizer,
    model_max_length=MODEL_MAX_LENGTH,
    padding_side="right",
    truncation_side="left",
    bos_token=BOS_TOKEN,
    eos_token=EOS_TOKEN,
    pad_token=PAD_TOKEN,
    unk_token=UNK_TOKEN,
)

print(tokenizer_pretrained.encode(smi))  # [0, 5, 5, 6, 5, ..., 4, 8, 1]
```